# How to apply javascript on checkbox with value total?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I try to print total value which is checked checkbox.
It is already work with `input type="checkbox">`
but It have made code with asp:checkbox/>.

I try but it is print NaN.

following code:
four checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox1" Text="Mobile" Value="70" onclick="checkcount(this);" />
<asp:Label ID="lbltotal" runat="server"   ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
int amount=0;
function checkcount(item)
{                      
      amount += parseInt(document.getElementById(item.id).value);
      alert(amount);
      document.getElementById("lbltotal").innerHTML = amount;
}
```

Comment: add .value after `document.getElementById(item.id)` because your `getElementById` is not getting any value...

Answer (score 3):

`parseInt(document.getElementById(item.id));`

should be:

`parseInt(document.getElementById(item.id).value);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
amount += parseInt(document.getElementById(item.id).value);
```